# Recursive HTML Parsing using C#

Tags: c#, html, csv

I'm trying to export `HTML` content (tables) to **CSV** files using `C#`, and based from my research here, one of the best ways to implement this is through the use of the **HTML Agility Pack**.

I haven't started coding and testing this yet because I need to be sure if it's doable first. The `HTML` table from the website is actually getting push messages from the server so its contents are updated real-time, so a change can happen all the time. What I would like to do is to be able to export the table to **CSV** every after there's a change in the table (e.g. row added, row deleted, cell contents modified, etc).

I am not sure if this can be done using **HTML agility pack**, or can be done using `C#` at all.

Please advise and thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes it can be done in C#. Yes, HTML Agility Pack is useful for *parsing* the HTML (but doesn't "do anything" beyond HTML access).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I understand that HTML Agility Pack is the way to go to parse the HTML. But, how will my C# program "know" that a change occurred on the table? To illustrate further: for example, the website is opened in my browser, then my C# application is also running "waiting" for updates on the table displayed in the browser. The browser receives a push message from the web server and a new row was added to the table. How will the C# program know this? Thank you!

Comment: The "push" probably comes from javascript checking for updates every X miliseconds.  For this you would need a full on web browser that will do javascript interpretation. You might be able to cook something up by using the WebBrowser class

Comment: What is 'recursive' about your problem/question?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is dynamically updating data it sounds like a headless browser would be a better fit for what you're looking to do. Something like [espion.io](http://espion.io/) or [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/). A headless browser would allow you to respond to these data pushes and capture the html for further processing.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth! I'll have a look into these two.